# Regex to check string contains only Hex characters

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have never done regex before, and I have seen they are very useful for working with strings. I saw a few [tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (for example) but I still cannot understand how to make a simple Java regex check for hexadecimal characters in a string.

The user will input in the text box something like: `0123456789ABCDEF` and I would like to know that the input was correct otherwise if something like `XTYSPG456789ABCDEF` when return false.

Is it possible to do that with a regex or did I misunderstand how they work?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a regular expression:

```
^[0-9A-F]+$
```

Explanation:

```
^            Start of line.
[0-9A-F]     Character class: Any character in 0 to 9, or in A to F.
+            Quantifier: One or more of the above.
$            End of line.
```

---

To use this regular expression in Java you can for example call the `matches` method on a String:

```
boolean isHex = s.matches("[0-9A-F]+");
```

Note that `matches` finds only an exact match so you don't need the start and end of line anchors in this case. See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/o8Sop)

You may also want to allow both upper and lowercase A-F, in which case you can use this regular expression:

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$
```

Comment: If to allow lowercase i should do like this `^[0-9a-fA-F]+$`? and how does one actually implements it, I mean is this correct `if(labelA.getText().equals(^[0-9A-F]+$)) {...}`? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: If you are using this same test multiple times, it would be more efficient to compile the pattern once (`Pattern hex = Pattern.compile("^[0-9A-F]+$")`) and then test by `hex.matcher(string).matches()`.

Comment: By the way, the `^` and `$` anchors are not necessary here, since `matches()` always matches the whole string.

Comment: Its a little old to reply to this comment. But i was trying out the above solution it fails when the string has "0x" at the start
I tried `^(0x|0X)?[0-9A-Fa-f]+$"` but it fails too... 
any help here :(

Comment: @Uday: **Create a new question.** And you'll need to provide more information about what you are doing. When you create your question remember to include what programming language you are using, what code you've written so far, what input strings you are testing on, what actually happens, what you wanted to happen, etc. The more information you provide, the more likely someone can help you.

Comment: The one that contains in any case should be on top. Many applications (unfortunately) do output lowercase and it really should not matter. Furthermore, the `+` is problematic since an empty message is perfectly fine in many circumstances (e.g. when using hex to represent bytes rather than a single number);  it should really have been a `*` or an additional note should be made that this is for numbers, and that it supposes that initial zero values digits are acceptable.

Answer (score 33):

May be you want to use the POSIX character class **`\p{XDigit}`**, so:

## `^\p{XDigit}+$`

Additionally, if you plan to use the regular expression very often, it is recommended to use a constant in order to avoid recompile it each time, e.g.:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("^\\p{XDigit}+$");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()
    );  // prints "true"
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for `\p{XDigit}` is pre-defined

Comment: Unless you want maximal compatibility with other regex machines, because it is pre-defined **for Java regex**.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, the given answer is not totally correct.  The problem arises because the numbers 0-9 are also decimal values.  PART of what you have to do is to test for 00-99 instead of just 0-9 to ensure that the lower values are not decimal numbers.  Like so:

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+$
```

To say these have to come in pairs!  Otherwise - the string is something else!  :-)

Example:

```
   (Pick one)
   var a = "1e5";
   var a = "10";
   var a = "314159265";
```

If I used the accepted answer in a regular expression it would return TRUE.

```
   var re1 = new RegExp( /^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/ );
   var re2 = new RegExp( /^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+$/ );

   if( re1.test(a) ){ alert("#1 = This is a hex value!"); }
   if( re2.test(a) ){ alert("#2 = This IS a hex string!"); }
     else { alert("#2 = This is NOT a hex string!"); }
```

Note that the "10" returns TRUE in both cases.  If an incoming string only has 0-9 you can NOT tell, easily if it is a hex value or a decimal value UNLESS there is a missing zero in front of off length strings (hex values always come in pairs - ie - Low byte/high byte).  But values like "34" are both perfectly valid decimal OR hexadecimal numbers.  They just mean two different things.

Also note that "3.14159265" is not a hex value no matter which test you do because of the period.  But with the addition of the "{2}" you at least ensure it really is a hex string rather than something that LOOKS like a hex string.

Comment: I think this is slightly out of scope for this question, since it did not mention byte pairs.  The validation depends entirely on the hex representation you require.  Both 129h and ACEh are valid hex numbers, they just aren't valid byte pairs.

Comment: Also, 3.14159265 is a valid [real number in hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Real_numbers).

Comment: #1 above: Actually, just because I didn't use YOUR term (ie: byte pairs) does not mean I did not say it (note: "To say these have to come in pairs!"). You are using a different method (ie: ###h). The "h" says it is hex (to you) to me 0x## means hex. Thus, 129h in Javascript may or may not mean hex values just like 0x## can mean a hex value.

Comment: #2 above: The value of "3.14159265" did NOT mean it was a hex value in the past. What would happen is it would just whack off everything after the period. It MIGHT now mean a hex value but in truth - hex does not do fractions. Hex does integers. Can you please show a link where you JUST say something like "var a = 3.14152965;" and then just show it as a hex value. NO FUNCTIONS. NO LIBRARIES. Just plain Javascript. Thanks! :-)