# Ruby, check if string is all valid hex characters?

Tags: ruby

I have to check if a 4 character string is all valid hex, I found another question which demonstrates exactly what I want to do but it's Java: [Regex to check string contains only Hex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317320/regex-to-check-string-contains-only-hex-characters)

How can I accomplish this?

I read the ruby docs for Regular expressions, but I don't understand how to return a true or false based on this match?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In ruby regex \h matches a hex digit and \H matches a non-hex digit.

So
`!str[/\H/]` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
if str =~ /^[0-9A-F]+$/
```

does the trick. If you want case insensitive then:

```
str =~ /^[0-9A-F]+$/i
```

Comment: This returns `nil` when I evaluate it against "f0a1"

Comment: Depends on whether you want it case sensitive.

Comment: but I'm confused because then it either returns `0` or `nil`, is there just a way to see if it matches?

Comment: Yes because `nil` is a false value so that means it didn't match whereas `0` means that it matched on the first character.

Comment: Ruby string's =~ will returns the position where the match starts, or nil if there is no match. You can use ` x = !!(str =~ /^[0-9A-F]+$/i)` to get x is `true` while matched, and vice versa. But just like Jakub's example, just put the matching in a if statement is more clear and easy.

Comment: @JosephSilvashy, you can also do this: `/^[0-9A-F]$/i === str`. [Regexp#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) expression always returns true of false.

Answer (score 2):

```
pattern = /^[[:xdigit:]]+$/
```

And then just check:

```
if  pattern === your_string
if /^[[:xdigit:]]+$/ === your_string
```

or with

```
if your_string.match?(/^[[:xdigit:]]+$/)
```