# Check if string has only `0` and `1`

Tags: ruby, regex

I am supposed to get a string and make sure that it represents a binary number like `"101011"`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075515) deals with hexadecimal strings, but I do not know how I should replace the letter `H` in the regex in statement `!str[/\H/]`. Could you help me?

Comment: `[01]+` this regex should work, but I don't know how to implement it in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four ways using `String` methods:

```
str1 = '100100110'
str2 = '100100210'
```

**[String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete)**

```
str1.delete('01') == '' #=> true
str2.delete('01') == '' #=> false
```

**[String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr)**

```
str1.tr('01','') == '' #=> true
str2.tr('01','') == '' #=> false
```

**[String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)**

```
str1.gsub(/[01]/,'') == '' #=> true
str2.gsub(/[01]/,'') == '' #=> false
```

**[String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count)**

```
str1.count('01') == str1.size #=> true
str2.count('01') == str2.size #=> false
```

Comment: You forgot the regexes :)

Comment: `str1.count('01') == str1.size` seems to be most efficient among all  answers (yours and others)

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward way using regex is:

```
"101011" !~ /[^01]/
```

Comment: Is regex evaluation O(n) operation in this case, n being length of string?

Comment: I've noticed that you have a particular fondness for`!~`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't particularly try to use it; I just think what is most straightforward, and it happened to be this. It just happens that no one else on this site uses it, so I become the one ending up showing its use.

Comment: I'll do my best to remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
"101011".chars.all? {|x| x =~ /[01]/} # true if binary, else false
```

Comment: A small suggestion: use `each_char` rather than than `chars` whenever it provides fodder for an `Enumerable` method.