# Masked input to allow only hex colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

using the jQuery Validate plugin or maybe manually with jQuery, I'd like to create an input field which accepts values with a '#' sign at the beginning, and 6 other characters. So, the input would accept something like this:

`#fff, #ff0000, #f00f`, but would decline '1232131231', or something else that doesn't match with the mask. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317320/regex-to-check-string-contains-only-hex-characters

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to make it only accept # straight out of the box, but what you can do is make it accept only numbers, and then add in the # to the beginning once submitted.

Comment: There is a way: regex.

Comment: Yes, wouldn't that not be straight out of the box like I said. regex is one way, it will take a little more coding then just adding it to the end though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
<input type="text" id="color">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#color').on('keyup', function() {
        if (/^#\d{6}$/.test($(this).val())) {
            console.log("it's a hex color");
        } else {
            console.log("it's not a hex color");
        }
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QEsGY/