# String MUST contain a hexadecimal value - Regex for this?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that must contain at least one hexadecimal value (0-9 A-F) and nothing else. How do I check this using regex?

I have tried the regex below, but it doesn't work as intended.

`.*A-F\\d+.*`

Thanks

Comment: Use `".*[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}.*"` with `matches`.

Comment: Why is this regex matching with the string "GFD"?

Comment: Because  it contains `FD`. If the whole string must contain hex values,use `^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+$` ([as per the post I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26784972/3832970)).